# Framework for automating in the game dev industry?

Tags: automated-testing

I've worked in ecommerce QA for `3 years now, and I am very familiar with selenium, as this has become kind of the industry standard for browser automation.  Is there something similar for testing games?  How does automation work in the game dev world?

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the tech powering your game. Unity has such testing tools ([link](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2013/12/18/unity-test-tools-released/)).